# Change value name based on two conditions in R

Tags: r

I have condition in column 1 (emp_title) and condition in column 2 (emp_length), and with these conditions I want to change values from column 2.

Basically what I want is: if column 2 has "NA" and if column 1 has "", then in column 2 change "NA" to "0".

I am new in this programming world, but everything I have tried is not working.

My first try was this one:

with(credit_data, ifelse(emp_title == "", "0", emp_length))

But this way I am missing one of the condition. And it doesn't seem to work.

Thank you!

Comment: Hi! You can combine multiple conditions using [logical operators](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/Logic.html). In this case, you can do something like this inside your ifelse `column_1== "" & is.na(column_2)`, note the `&` used.

Comment: Thank you, it doesn't seem to work. I am starting to believe it's because my "column_1" is defined as a character, do you know if it could be because of that?

Answer (score 0):

For dummy data `df1` I made, you may try,

```
df1 <- data.frame(
  emp_title = c("","a","b","c",""),
  emp_length = c(NA,1,2,3,4)
)

  emp_title emp_length
1                   NA
2         a          1
3         b          2
4         c          3
5                    4

df1$emp_length[is.na(df1$emp_length) & (df1$emp_title == "")] <- 0
df1

  emp_title emp_length
1                    0
2         a          1
3         b          2
4         c          3
5                    4
```

Or using `dplyr` and `ifelse`,

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
  mutate(emp_length = ifelse(is.na(emp_length) & emp_title == "", 0, emp_length))

  emp_title emp_length
1                    0
2         a          1
3         b          2
4         c          3
5                    4
```

Comment: Hello, thank you a lot for your answer!! It doesn't seem to work for me, could it be because emp_title is defined as a chr (character)?